# Why Angular Hint suggests pascal cased names for controller and modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, batarang

It appears the Batarang plugin for Chrome has just updated. A new feature `Angular Hint` is added and gave me a bunch of warnings today. And there is an instruction that says:

**Name controllers according to best practices (9551)**

Controller names should start with an uppercase character and end with the suffix Controller. For example: UserController.

> Consider renaming homeController to HomeController.

Haven't we Angular developers always use camel-cased names for JavaScript object? Anyone can tell us why Batarang prefers the pascal case instead?

And more questions:

- Where can we find the documentation for the latest "best practices"?
- If we don't want to follow this "best practice" for the existing web apps, how to turn of that type of "Hints"?

Comment: Batarang can be turned off under `chrome://extensions/`. As I inspect scopes from the console anyway, indiscriminate hint spamming has rendered the extension useless to me.

Comment: I now completely uninstalled it.

Comment: I think Batarang updated again. And there is a checkbox to enable/disable Batarang now. We don't have to completely uninstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batarang suggests this, as controller functions are actually constructor functions, and constructor functions begin - by convention - with an uppercase character in JavaScript.

This is different from other artefacts, such as filters or services. They are written using a lowercase character, as they are not treated as constructors.

For controllers, it actually makes a lot of sense, as you may want to have multiple instances of a single controller within one single website.

In JavaScript, it's actually best practice to lowercase everything, except constructors: This way the developer knows when to use `new` with a function and when not to use it. The underlying problem is that technically there's no difference between a function and a constructor in JavaScript. Both are just functions, they just deal differently with the `this` keyword (and this is what `new` influences under the hoods).

For the "best practices" part… I'd go with the Angular [documentation on how to define controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider#register). There it says that it's a constructor (although, to be true, it's quite hidden).

As for how to turn it off… no, I'm sorry, I don't know whether this is actually possible (and if so, I don't know how to). On the other hand, I would recommend to ask yourself if you really want to do it differently, if there *IS* a common best practice.

Comment: Thanks, Golo. That does make sense. Do you know where to find the "best practice" documentation? and how can we temporarily disable `Angular Hint`? (My Chrome Console is now flooded with Angular Hint warnings.

Comment: PS: The console of my Chrome is flooded too, and the new Batarang version broke some websites (including the menu of the official Angular website itself), so I disabled it. I've never used it a lot, anyway.

Comment: Ugh.  Batarang is killing my page, too.